# xslt display for multiple values in a for loop

Tags: xml, xslt, tags

I am having an XML file which looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sqlserverinfo.xsl"?>

<root>

<details>

<Name>`SQLServer:General Statistics`</Name>

<p>
Active Temp Tables
</p>

<q>
4
</q>

<p>
Temp Tables Creation Rate
</p>

<q>41</q>

</details>

<details>

<Name>SQLServer:locks</Name>

<p>Active locks</p>

<q>10</q>

<p>Temp Locks</p>

<q>19</q>

</details>
```

Now what i am looking for is having a html output using xslt to show up this information in a table format.

Something like this.

SQLServer:General Statistics

counter                 counter_value

Temp Tables                 4
Temp creation rates        41

SQLServer:locks

```
counter                          counter_value

Active Locks                            4

Temp Locks                              41
```

i.e i have my multiple **`<p>`** tag and **`<q>`** tag nested

so the problem now is if i run a loop for **`<p>`** the tag value of **`<q>`** should also be displayed but i am not able to get the answer of how to do that
does anyone knows the solution??? 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting the value of:

```
following-sibling::q
```

This is assuming your "loop" is in the context of `<p>`. Seeing your XSLT would help to pinpoint the answer.

Note that your result does not match your XML source. Also, your XML source is missing a closing `</root>` tag.